# Full day event not correctly showed on free busy request

Tags: google-calendar-api

i am having an issue when call free busy request on Google Calendar API.

Full day event are not showed correctly.

If I have an event on 23/04/2018 (full day event)

the FreeBusy request return this:

```
{"calendars":{"null":{"busy":[],"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"notFound"}]},"<MYEMAILADDRESS>":{"busy":[{"end":"2018-04-23T08:15:00.000Z","start":"2018-04-23T08:00:00.000Z"}]}},"kind":"calendar#freeBusy","timeMax":"2018-04-24T06:00:00.000Z","timeMin":"2018-04-23T05:00:00.000Z"}
```

As you can see the start/end time is not useful.

Otherwise if i get the event from event list API, the event has not a time but only date (correct).

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883417/google-calendar-api-v3-android-get-all-day-events-for-freebusyrequest